# Getting (Mac)Vim to Work With RVM

Tags: ruby, macvim

I'm using RVM to manage Ruby installs and Gems, and MacVim to create and edit Ruby files.

I have a key command in my `~/.vimrc` mapped to evaluate a loaded Ruby file and print the output. It looks something like this:

```
map <Leader>r :w! <bar> !ruby %<CR>
```

Within a zsh shell, the `ruby` command respects my RVM setting. In MacVim, however, the `ruby` command loads the default Ruby at `/usr/bin/ruby`, and it ignores RVM entirely. Is there any way to get MacVim to recognize the Ruby version I set with RVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in the vim plugin I've just started working on. It's called [rvm_ruby.vim](http://github.com/jcf/rvm_ruby.vim) and gives you ex commands that will reach RVM ruby executables.

You'd use something like `:Ruby %` to reach the ruby version you were using when you launched MacVim (assuming you did it using `mvim` in a login shell).

There's also a `:Gem` ex command that targets RVM's gem command.

Comment: that does the trick, and is definitely a better solution than mine. thanks very much!